What SQL_MODE controls LIMIT in multiple-table UPDATE statements in MySQL 8?
I have a query like this:
update customers c
    inner join installations i on i.customer_id=c.id
    inner join assets a on a.installation_id=i.id
    set c.source_id='SOME-SOURCE-ID'
    where a.serial_no='ABC123'
    limit 1;

On my local MySQL instance (Server version: 8.0.32 MySQL Community Server - GPL) this query is allowed and works as expected.
On a shared instance on AWS (Server version: 8.0.32 Source distribution), I get the following error:
ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

I do understand this error and what I can do to solve it, but what I can't work out is why it works on my local MySQL instance, but not on the shared instance.
The documentation says:

For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

But there's no mention about this being subject to some sort of mode or setting. I suspect though, as the version number is the same between the two instances, it must be subject to some sort of stricter SQL mode, but can't find anything in the SQL modes documentation that sounds like it would relate to this.
For completeness, the modes on my local instance are: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
When I do SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sql_mode" on the shared AWS instance, the value is empty.
What is the cause of these two MySQL instances behaving differently when trying to apply LIMIT to an UPDATE statement involving multiple-tables?

even if it uis allows without an oder b the limit makes no sense

@nbk - To "make sense" turn it into a SELECT.  (But then notice that there is no ORDER BY -- hence non-deterministic.)

@RickJames i provided an answer that add an order by to make it deterministic and works with mysql and mariadb. Still he will get  always the same result, what not means that it is the result that he wants

I am facing the same issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/341755/caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-usage-of-update-and-limit

You are not running MySQL on your local instance. No version of MySQL (as of the most recent 9.0.1) supports LIMIT with multi-table UPDATE statements. No SQL_MODE value or any other option can change this.
MariaDB 10.3 and later have implemented support for LIMIT with multi-table UPDATE. Run this query:
SELECT VERSION();

You will find that you are running a version of MariaDB Server locally. The server version determines support for SQL syntax and features, not the client version.
You may have gotten the MySQL 8.0.32 version from a client you are using to connect to MariaDB, or you may have mistakenly assumed the versions were the same.
Be aware that MariaDB and MySQL are not the same product. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot since then, and are no longer compatible.
If you intend to deploy your application to a hosted server that uses MySQL 8.0.32, you should use the same version of MySQL Server as you develop locally. MariaDB is not a compatible replacement for MySQL Server, and you will run into many of these kinds of gotchas, leading to surprises when you deploy to your production server.
Always use the same brand and version of software in development as those you will deploy to.

Hi Bill, thanks for the answer, and that's certainly something I considered - but no, that's not the case here. It's definitely MySQL: https://pastebin.com/uKxP6Yj8 It's the official MySQL server image from Docker Hub. In that paste, I'm interacting with the server via Laravel Sail/docker-compose. implementation here: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/bin/sail
It's NOT mariadb.

Cannot reproduce. Tested on MySQL 8.0.37 on my local laptop, and on MySQL 8.0.36 on dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/QwQqw99l I get the "Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT" error in both cases. Read the following bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84256. It suggests this behavior is as designed (the bug is about multi-table UPDATE with ORDER BY, but I suppose it also applies to LIMIT, which only makes sense if you use ORDER BY).

Basically you need to rewrite your query like with an CTE
The CTE has to be tested, as i don't know excatly which customer you actuall want and this is determined by the ORDER BY in the CTE
WITH CTE as (
SELECT c.id FROM customers c
    inner join installations i on i.customer_id=c.id
    inner join assets a on a.installation_id=i.id    
    where a.serial_no='ABC123'
    ORDER BY c.id 
    limit 1)
update customers c
INNER JOIN CTE c1 ON c.id = c1.id
    set c.source_id='SOME-SOURCE-ID';

