Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT
I want to execute a sql in MySQL 8 like this:
UPDATE shop_product sp
    LEFT JOIN product_line pl ON sp.line_id = pl.id
SET sp.online_status = pl.online_status, sp.recommend = pl.recommend, sp.sync_version = 'Xh4Fzi1idNpI3MLt', sp.top_quality = pl.top_quality
WHERE sp.shop_id = '22'
    AND pl.id IS NOT NULL
    AND sp.sync_version != 'Xh4Fzi1idNpI3MLt'
LIMIT 1000

in my production environment, the MySQL 8.0.34 shows error:
Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

in the local develop MySQL 8.0.30 it works fine. Does different MySQL using different rule? Am I missing something? is it possible to let this sql work in the version of MySQL 8.0.34? or other configuration should I tweak. I have checked this configuration in both side are off:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates'

I also tried this demo sql in mysql 8.0.30 and it works:
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id int,
  source_id VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE installations (
  id int,
  customer_id int
);


CREATE TABLE assets (
  installation_id int,
  serial_no varchar(10)
);

update customers c
    inner join installations i on i.customer_id=c.id
    inner join assets a on a.installation_id=i.id
    set c.source_id='SOME-SOURCE-ID'
    where a.serial_no='ABC123'
    limit 1;

and this is the execute result with the test sql in MySQL 8.0.30:


UPDATE have no LIMIT, it makes no sense there so get rid of it without any data we can't understand , which data must be updated

I read the manual from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/update.html, does this version support limit? The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

In the manual is stated

For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

and

Multiple-table syntax:


UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET assignment_list
[WHERE where_condition]

So for joined tables you can not use LIMIT or ORDER BY
You can something like
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id int,
  source_id VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE installations (
  id int,
  customer_id int
);


CREATE TABLE assets (
  installation_id int,
  serial_no varchar(10)
);



update customers c
    inner join installations i on i.customer_id=c.id
    inner join ( SELECT MAX(installation_id) as installation_id
  FROM assets WHERE serial_no='ABC123') a on a.installation_id=i.id
    set c.source_id='SOME-SOURCE-ID'
    


fiddle
there could be other solutions, that would fit better as i don't know exactly what you want to do

why the multiple-table syntax, with limit works in MySQL 8.0.30?

sometimes they test things out, but keep to the manual, this should always work
